# Spring security handles session through JSESSIONID. But What happens with a AJAX requests, do they contain session information(i.e JSESSIONID)

Tags: ajax, authentication, spring-security, session-cookies, jsessionid

When using Spring Security: after a user is authenticated, subsequent request are validated using `JSESSIONID` header field(cookie field) by Spring Security filters.
So, on subsequent requests if I am submitting a `form` or making a resource request, the browser would automatically include the `JSESSIONID` and on the server side the `JSESSIONID` would be validated by the Spring Security filter and if every things fine then the `form` would be accepted or the request would be served.

But after authentication, if the jsp or the front-end pages has a AJAX(or jQuery or dojo) request to be made to the server what would happen. **What I am not sure is will the brower include the `JSESSIONID` header field even with AJAX request?**

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.  The `JSESSIONID` is automatically passed along in AJAX requests.

As long as the domain of the `JSESSIONID` cookie matches the domain of the AJAX request, then this will be handled automatically.

Comment: Just a heads up, Ajax POST requests will require you to include the `csfr` header also, unless you have switched `csfr` off.